# How can I get a brick out of my drain pipe?

Tags: plumbing

There's a brick inside my outside drain, and I can't get it out. It's stuck in there, and the drain is now overflowing with all sorts of things. It's already too deep. I tried to hit it in as hard as I could, hoping I could break the brick in pieces, but no luck. I'm stuck now.

Comment: What do you mean *outside drain*? Can you post a picture?

Comment: Not getting to upload or paste a picture, but its the drain on the ouside of my house next to the kitchen were al the house water is runing to the outside, and toilets, al pipes meet there, from there I'm sure it goes somewhere.

Comment: If it is a sewage pipe and it is openly draining somewhere (how could you tell their is a brick in it?), you have a far bigger problem.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. OP hasn't adequately described the drain and hasn't been back.

Answer (score 2):

First, do not attempt to break the brick into any more pieces, should you succeed these pieces may get lodged further down the pipe making it that **much more complicated (and expensive)** to resolve.

Unfortunately the only solution will be to cut the section of pipe that the brick is stuck in and remove it.

**Call a plumber**: it already sounds like you are in over your head; a qualified professional will be able to resolve the situation for you without further compromising the drainage system.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see it, can you "grab" it with something like a long drill and expansion bolt, then pull it out. If it's really stuck, be prepared to have the pipe break and then need to replace pipe anyway.